# How to setup a 3-tier web application project

Tags: python, design-patterns, model-view-controller, orm, sqlalchemy

**EDIT:**

*I have added [MVC] and [design-patterns] tags to expand the audience for this question as it is more of a generic programming question than something that has direclty to do with Python or SQLalchemy. It applies to all applications with business logic and an ORM.

The basic question is if it is better to keep business logic in separate modules, or to add it to the classes that our ORM provides:*

We have a flask/sqlalchemy project for which we have to setup a structure to work in. There are two valid opinions on how to set things up, and before the project really starts taking off we would like to make our minds up on one of them.
If any of you could give us some insights on which of the two would make more sense and why, and what the advantages/disadvantages would be, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

My example is an HTML letter that needs to be sent in bulk and/or displayed to a single user. The letter can have sections that display an invoice and/or a list of articles for the user it is addressed to.

---

**Method 1:**
Split the code into 3 tiers - 1st tier: web interface, 2nd tier: processing of the letter, 3rd tier: the models from the ORM (sqlalchemy).
The website will call a server side method in a class in the 2nd tier, the 2nd tier will loop through the users that need to get this letter and it will have internal methods that generate the HTML and replace some generic fields in the letter, with information for the current user. It also has internal methods to generate an invoice or a list of articles to be placed in the letter.

*In this method, the 3rd tier is only used for fetching data from the database and perhaps some database related logic like generating a full name from a users' first name and last name. The 2nd tier performs most of the work*.

**Method 2:**
Split the code into the same three tiers, but only perform the loop through the collection of users in the 2nd tier.

*The methods for generating HTML, invoices and lists of articles are all added as methods to the model definitions in tier 3 that the ORM provides. The 2nd tier performs the loop, but the actual functionality is enclosed in the model classes in the 3rd tier*.

We concluded that both methods could work, and both have pros and cons:

Method 1:

- separates business logic completely from database access
- prevents that importing an ORM model also imports a lot of methods/functionality that we might not need, also keeps the code for the model classes more compact.
- might be easier to use when mocking out ORM models for testing

Method 2:

- seems to be in line with the way Django does things in Python
- allows simple access to methods: when a model instance is present, any function it
  performs can be immediately called. (in my example: when I have a letter-instance available, I can directly call a method on it that generates the HTML for that letter)
- you can pass instances around, having all appropriate methods at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you use the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern for this kind of stuff, but most web frameworks in python have dropped the "Controller" part for since they believe that it is an unnecessary component. In my development I have realized, that this is somewhat true: I can live without it. That would leave you with two layers: The view and the model.

The question is where to put business logic now. In a practical sense, there are two ways of doing this, at least two ways in which I am confrontet with where to put logic:

- Create special internal view methods that handle logic, that might be needed in more than one view, e.g. `_process_list_data`
- Create functions that are related to a model, but not directly tied to a single instance inside a corresponding model module, e.g. `check_login`.

To elaborate: I use the first one for strictly **display-related** methods, i.e. they are somehow concerned with processing data for displaying purposes. My above example, `_process_list_data` lives inside a view class (which groups methods by purpose), but could also be a normal function in a module. It recieves some parameters, e.g. the data list and somehow formats it (for example it may add additional view parameters so the template can have less logic). It then returns the data set to the original view function which can either pass it along or process it further.

The second one is used for most other logic which I like to keep out of my direct view code for easier testing. My example of `check_login` does this: It is a function that is not directly tied to display output as its purpose is to check the users login credentials and decide to either return a user or report a login failure (by throwing an exception, return `False` or returning `None`). However, this functionality is not directly tied to a model either, so it cannot live inside an ORM class (well it could be a `staticmethod` for the `User` object). Instead it is just a function inside a module (remember, this is Python, you should use the simplest approach available, and functions are there for something)

To sum this up: Display logic in the view, all the other stuff in the model, since most logic is somehow tied to specific models. And if it is not, create a new module or package just for logic of this kind. This could be a separate module or even a package. For example, I often create a `util` module/package for helper functions, that are not directly tied for any view, model or else, for example a function to format dates that is called from the template but contains so much python could it would be ugly being defined inside a template.

Now we bring this logic to your task: Processing/Creation of letters. Since I don't know exactly what processing needs to be done, I can only give general recommendations based on my assumptions.

Let's say you have some data and want to bring it into a letter. So for example you have a list of `articles` and a `costumer` who bought these articles. In that case, you already have the data. The only thing that may need to be done before passing it to the template is reformatting it in such a way that the template can easily use it. For example it may be desired to order the purchased articles, for example by the amount, the price or the article number. This is something that is independent of the model, the order is now only display related (you could have specified the order already in your database query, but let's assume you didn't). In this case, this is an operation your view would do, so your template has the data ready formatted to be displayed.

Now let's say you want to get the data to create a specifc letter, for example a list of articles the user bough over time, together with the date when they were bought and other details. This would be the model's job, e.g. create a query, fetch the data and make sure it is has all the properties required for this specifc task.

Let's say in both cases you with to retrieve a price for the product and that price is determined by a base value and some percentages based on other properties: This would make sense as a model *method*, as it operates on a single product or order instance. You would then pass the model to the template and call the price method inside it. But you might as well reformat it in such a way, that the call is made already in the view and the template only gets tuples or dictionaries. This would make it easier to pass the same data out as an API (see below) but it might not necessarily be the easiest/best way.

A good rule for this decision is to ask yourself **If I were to provide a JSON API additionally to my standard view, how would I need to modify my code to be as DRY as possible?**. If theoretical is not enough at the start, build some APIs for the templates and see where you need to change things to the API makes sense next to the views themselves. You may never use this API and so it does not need to be perfect, but it can help you figure out how to structure your code. However, as you saw above, this doesn't necessarily mean that you should do preprocessing of the data in such a way that you only return things that can be turned into JSON, instead you might want to make some JSON specifc formatting for the API view.

So I went on a little longer than I intended, but I wanted to provide some examples to you because that is what I missed when I started and found out those things via trial and error.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer, javex, but unfortunately, it leaves me none the wiser. MVC is a pattern we more or less follow, but even in a pattern the logic can be separated into multiple tiers. There is no reason to split a controller or a model into multiple modules if the need arises. The most basic question is if it is smarter to have -all logic- in the model, even logic that is only needed for a specific task, or to keep task-specific code separate from generic model-specific code.